# The last page is missing in react-paginate

Tags: reactjs, pagination

I decided to use "react-paginate" for my app using [npm react-paginate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-paginate). I have 10 pages, and they all appeared firstly, but when I start to paginate, the button number 10 for last page disappearing. Kan any one please help me with this!

[image]

Number 10 is missing down here:

[image]

```
 return (
            <div>
            <ReactPaginate
              previousLabel={'Previous'}
              nextLabel={'Next'}
              breakLabel={'...'}
              breakClassName={'break-me'}
              pageCount={ Math.ceil(products.length / productsPerPage)}
              marginPagesDisplayed={2}
              pageRangeDisplayed={5}
              onPageChange={ (e)=> {
                setFromProduct(e.selected+productsPerPage)}}
              containerClassName={'pagination'}
              subContainerClassName={'pages pagination'}
              activeClassName={'active'}
            />
            </div>
      );
```

Comment: Can you add code for  setFromProduct(e.selected+productsPerPage)?

Comment: There is no code, it just have useState(1) with default number 1. because it's ready paginaiton called react-paginate.